# how "expect(9).to be > 6" is valid expression?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In [RSpec doc](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-2/docs/built-in-matchers/comparison-matchers), I found something looking strange like

```
expect(9).to be > 6
```

I have no idea how above expression can be valid.

How can `>` come like this? I search rspec github, but found no clue.

Comment: Ruby is well-suited for expressive statements like this (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent to

```
expect(9).to(be > 6)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
expect(9).to(be.>(6))
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby you can override the `>` operator on a class, in this case the `RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Be` class which is what the `be` method returns.

If you want to check the source code the relevant part is [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/be.rb)